# How do I show something is piecewise linear?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis

I have an integral in which I have to show is piecewise linear with $2^K$ parts, what should the *work towards* goal be? Let's generalize:

$G(y)=\int_a^xg(y)dy$

Comment: Have you tried proving its derivative is constant on $2^K$ intervals?

Comment: First, I would try and guess the locations of the linear parts and then show that they are linear on each part. Unless you give us more information, we can't really say anything more.

Comment: let's say something like  $g(y)  =\Sigma_0^{2^K-1}g_i(y)$  ? I would need to perpetuate and find that the $g_i(y)$'s are constant?